# Объекты статических классов

Tags: java, объекты, static, inner

Здравствуйте уважаемые знатоки). Недавно в процессе изучения Java(путем прохождения javarush) наткнулся на вот такой код, вызвавший у меня когнитивный диссонанс:

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        EnglishTranslator englishTranslator = new EnglishTranslator();
        System.out.println(englishTranslator.translate());
    }

    public static abstract class Translator {
        public abstract String getLanguage();

        public String translate() {
            return "Я переводчик с " + getLanguage();
        }
    }

    public static class EnglishTranslator extends Translator {
        @Override
        public String getLanguage() {
            return "английского";
        }
    }
}
```

Он компилируется и нормально работает. 
Внимание вопрос: Зачем мы создаем экземпляр статического класса??

Следующий код не компилируется:

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        //EnglishTranslator englishTranslator = new EnglishTranslator();
        System.out.println(EnglishTranslator.translate()); //non-static method translate() cannot be
                                                           //referenced from a static context
    }

    public static abstract class Translator {
        public abstract String getLanguage();

        public String translate() {
            return "Я переводчик с " + getLanguage();
        }
    }

    public static class EnglishTranslator extends Translator {
        @Override
        public String getLanguage() {
            return "английского";
        }
    }
}
```

Если мы убираем модификатор *static* у класса *EnglishTranslator*, то получаем следующую ошибку:

```
Solution.this cannot be referenced from a static context
```

Так же мы можем вынести *Translator* и *EnglishTranslator* за *Solution* и убрать у них модификатор *static* это так же компилируется и работает.

**Помогите пожалуйста в этом всем разобраться.**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

В Java, класс, объявленный в другом классе, называется **вложенным** классом.

Существует два типа вложенных классов: **статические** и **нестатические**.

1. **Статический вложенный** класс (*static nested class*) – это класс, объявленный с модификатором `static`.
2. **Нестатический вложенный** класс (также называется **внутренним** классом, *inner class*) – это, собственно, класс, объявленный без модификатора `static`.

> Зачем мы создаем экземпляр статического класса?

Нестатический вложенный класс (внутренний класс) неявно содержит ссылку на экземпляр внешнего класса, за счет этого достигается доступ к нестатическим полям внешнего класса из внутреннего класса.

Так как внутренний класс содержит ссылку на экземпляр внешнего класса, то экземпляр внутреннего класса можно создать только в нестатических методах (или блоках) внешнего класса.

Так как Вы создаете экземпляр вложенного класса в **статическом** методе внешнего класса, т.е. без создания экземпляра внешнего класса, то этот вложенный класс должен быть **статическим**.

> Следующий код не компилируется:

В этом случае Вы пытаетесь вызвать нестатический метод `translate()` без создания экземпляра класса, чего делать нельзя.

Казалось бы, решение этой проблемы заключаться в объявлении методов `translate()` и `getLanguage()` статическими, однако в данном случае этот вариант не сработает, так как метод `getLanguage()` является абстрактным методом, а абстрактный метод нельзя объявить статическим.

> Если мы убираем модификатор `static` у класса `EnglishTranslator`, то получаем следующую ошибку:
>
> ```
> Solution.this cannot be referenced from a static context
> ```

Если Вы уберете модификатор `static` у класса `EnglishTranslator`, то этот класс станет внутренним классом, а внутренний класс, как было сказано выше, неявно содержит ссылку на экземпляр внешнего класса.

Вы создаете экземпляр класса `EnglishTranslator` в статическом методе внешнего класса, который может быть вызван без создания экземпляра внешнего класса, следовательно, сослаться на `this` внешнего класса в этом методе Вы не сможете, откуда следует, что в этом методе невозможно создать экземпляр внутреннего класса `EnglishTranslator`.

> Так же мы можем вынести Translator и EnglishTranslator за Solution и убрать у них модификатор static это так же компилируется и работает.

В таком случае эти классы перестанут быть вложенными, и их экземпляры можно будет создавать и в статических и в нестатических методах других классов.

---

### И самое главное

Изучать язык Java (*собственно, как и любой другой язык программирования*) без чтения соответствующих **классических** книг – это **очень и очень плохая идея**.

Статьи в интернете (которые могут быть некорректными, например, в некоторых из них **ошибочно** указано, что в Java объекты передаются при вызове по ссылке), всякие там видео-уроки (это вообще для ленивых, типа как фильм посмотреть с пачкой чипсов и банкой колы) – это не то, с помощью чего следует изучать подобные **фундаментальные** вещи.

Да, про некоторые моменты можно почитать какие-то статьи, но в приоритете всегда должно быть авторитетное пособие.

По поводу JavaRush – да, ребята предоставляют неплохую практику по языку, но перед выполнением этих практических вещей просто необходимо освоить теорию по выбранной теме в книге.

Так что советую Вам всегда держать под рукой (не только держать, но и вникать :)) что-нибудь из классики по Java, например: Шилдт, Хорстманн, Эккель.