# Статичный asynctask и ошибка Can not be references from a static context

Tags: java, android, static, context, inner

Доброго. Делаю сервис получения времени, который отдаёт его через интерфейс. Скелет кода такой:

```
public class TimeSyncService extends Service {

private static final String TAG = "TimeSyncService";
private static final String NTP_SERVER_IP = "192.168.128.5";
private static final getNtpListenet ntpListener = null;

public interface getNtpListenet {
    void onTimeReceived(String fileName);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: ");
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: ");
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    return START_STICKY;
}

class JobResult
{
    boolean has_error = false;
    boolean synced = false;
}

static class getNtpTime extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JobResult> {

    private getNtpListenet listener;

    @Override
    protected JobResult doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        JobResult jobResult = new JobResult(); //ошибка




        return jobResult;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JobResult jobResult) {
        super.onPostExecute(jobResult);

        listener.onTimeReceived("time here");
    }
}
```

}

В строке JobResult jobResult = new JobResult(); получаю ошибку "Can not be references from a static context". Смысл ошибки понятен, но как её правильно исправить в данном случае ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Так как внутренний класс содержит ссылку на экземпляр внешнего класса, то экземпляр внутреннего класса можно создать только в нестатических методах (или блоках) внешнего класса.

[Взято отсюда.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/628927/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2/628931#628931)

В вашем случае решением может быть объявление `JobResult` статическим.
А еще лучше, просто самостоятельным классом.